# Listing data from different columns without joins

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables with a column "date" in each table. How can I retrieve data from these columns ordering by date? Thank you.

Comment: union query. But to be more specific, can you show your table structure, and the expected result? and something that you have tried?

Comment: i did not try, because have no idea where to start from. The project is like mini-Instagram. I have tables "photoes", "comments" and "likes", each having the "date" column. I need the user to be able to see who posted photo from those users who our user is following, who liked his photoes and who commeded to his own photoes. And order this data by date. How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need a UNION ALL query. Something like this:

```
SELECT id, date, 'photo' as type FROM photoes
UNION ALL
SELECT id, date, 'comment' as type FROM comments
UNION ALL
SELECT id, date, 'like' as type FROM likes
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: thanks for the example, this is exactly what I needed :) Now I can differentiate the data